# lodctr /r error code 5 while being Administrator

Tags: cmd, performancecounter, administrator, error-code

In order to fix a problem with performance counters, I have to follow a Microsoft tutorial.
It starts with this command "lodctr /R" but I'm getting error code 5 which is normally due to not having the permission.
The thing is in my case I'm running the cmd as administrator and the user I'm using have the administrator authority.
Anyone knows what can I do from here ?
Thanks in advance